# What functions satisfy this condition?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I'm interested in finding all functions which satisfy the following relation:

$\forall_\theta: arcTan(\frac{Im[f(\theta) + g(\theta)]}{Re[f(\theta)+g(\theta)]}) = k$

(Not important for the answer: but my motivation for the question is that I want to see if there are any nontrivial functions when summed up can have a complex "phase" that is a constant.)

Is the only condition when this is satisfied is when f and g are constants?

Comment: All functions or just holomorphic?

Comment: To be clear: are $f$ and $g$ functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$?

Comment: This obviously holds whenever $f+g$ is constant, which does not necessarily imply that $f$ and $g$ are constant functions

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I think just holomorphic is sufficient. (Although I am interested in knowing how different it makes finding a solution)

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yes - similar to a differential equation's "general solution" is there a way of figuring out what set of functions satisfy this constraint?

Comment: @StevenSagona Please note that you just made two contradictory comments. A "holomorphic" function would need to be defined over $\Bbb C$, but you just said that these are functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$ (unless I misinterpreted your "yes"). Also, note that my second comment answers the question that you have literally asked, namely: "is the only condition when this is satisfied is when f and g are constants", to which the answer is no. If you would like to expand on the question, please edit your post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

A function $h(\theta) = f(\theta) + g(\theta)$ will satisfy this "constant phase $k$" property if and only if it is of the form
$$
h(\theta) = \phi(\theta)e^{ik}
$$
for some $\phi:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.